# Service for ServerSocket - should it be in a separate thread?

Tags: android, sockets

I'm writing a simple application that uses `sockets`. I have an activity that launches a service after a button press; in short, `onStart` in this service does something like this:

```
ss=new ServerSocket(portNum);
Socket socket=ss.accept();
//some other unrelated stuff
```

I though that services can run in background independent from activities (I'm new to android and, in fact, this is my first app), but my activity freezes until `ss.accept()` is done (I mean, until the client connects - the button remains in pressed state and I can't do anything). Is this behaviour normal or should I look for an error somewhere in my code? Or maybe put this piece of code in a separate thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, in Android local services use the same UI thread. That's why your activity freezes. You should create service, make a thread in this service and run your command in another thread.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Though it's kinda strange they did it that way.